# How to create functor instance for phantom type where first argument phantom?

Tags: haskell, functor

One of the exercises in the http://haskellbook.com is to write a functor instance for

```
data EvilGoateeConst a b =
  GoatyConst b
```

My attempt is

```
instance Functor (EvilGoateeConst a) where
  fmap f (GoatyConst b) = GoatyConst b
```

The simplest fix is just to switch the arguments to the type constructor, but I guess that is verboten. What is the simplest way of fixing this without changing the original type?

(And I am not applying the function because that makes the compiler barf, but I think it still is a valid functor according to the laws.)

Comment: How does applying `f` 'make the compiler barf'?

Comment: @Lee I had an error somewhere else, sorry!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are *overthinking* this problem - look at the type of `fmap` in this case it should be:

```
fmap :: (b -> c) -> EvilGoateeConst a b -> EvilGoateeConst a c
```

The reason is that `EvilGoateeConst a b ~ (EvilGoateeConst a) b` and so `EvilGoateeConst a :: * -> *` fits exactly the *kind* a `Functor` instance need to have but now the `a` is **fixed** and the functor might change the `b` instead

---

ok I don't know how to say more without totally spoiling it so don't look if you want to try it yourself but the answer is just:

```
instance Functor (EvilGoateeConst a) where
  fmap f (GoatyConst b) = GoatyConst (f b)
```